# Graph with $50$ vertices and $392$ edges with no $4$ independent vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

I need an example of a graph with $50$ vertices and $392$ edges, with no independent set of size $4$. The graph should be loopless, and I think multiple edges are allowed. I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Multiple edged graphs can't be loopless.

Comment: @ajotatxe I thought a loop was when a vertex is connected to itself?  It seems you can have multiple edges with no loops.

Comment: Sorry, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What would the complement of such a graph satisfy?

It would be a graph with $\binom{50}{2}-392=833$ and no $K_4$. By Turan's theorem the graph with the most edges and no $K_4$ is the complete 3-partite graph $K_{17,17,16}$, and it is unique up to isomorphism. This graph has exactly $17\cdot17+17\cdot16+17\cdot16=833$ edges.

So the only graph that works is the complement of $K_{17,17,16}$ which consists of two copies of $K_{17}$ and one $K_{16}$.

This method can be used to solve the problem in its generality. In other words if you want a graph on $n$ vertices and $e$ edges without independent sets of size $k$ take $k-1$ complete graphs such that the differences between their sizes is at most $1$ and such that the sum of their vertices is $n$, if this graph has more than $e$ edges then the graph you are looking for is unnatainable. Otherwise you can add edges untill you have $e$ edges and that graph will satisfy what you want. This can all be justified using Turan as I did for your example.

Comment: Oh, I have not made it to that theorem yet. So this would also prove that every graph with 50 vertices and *less than* 392 edges has 4 independent vertices.  Nice.

Comment: Yes it would. Happy to help !

Answer (score 3):

Two copies of $K_{17}$, and a $K_{16}$.

$17+17+16=50$ vertices and $136+136+120 = 392$ edges.

By the pigeonhole principle, of any $4$ vertices selected, two will be in the same $K$ graph and thus connected.